# "zsh: command not found: flutter" after the path is given in ".zshrc" file

Tags: flutter, zsh

So, I did all the steps correctly, but still I'm getting the error.
I had googled for solution, still no answer is found for this problem.
By default my Mac uses **zsh**.
`export PATH="$PATH: /Users/venkateshmunaga/Developer/flutter/bin"`  is the command I have give in the **.zshrc** file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFHD9.png)

And also I have downloaded flutter using the zip file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the space between colon and slash. :)